# How to check if what an iterator points to exists

Tags: c++, math, vector, iterator

I have a loop that iterates through a vector of classes. It finds a `std::vector` within the class and find a `glm::vec3` at a particular element. Within the loop I have a iterator that points to the next class.

I use this data to calculate some vectors.

How do I check that `(*nextSegIt)` actually exists? When `segIt` reaches the last element it will point somewhere random I guess.

I have tried an if statement to check if it is `NULL` or if it is the end of the vector array but neither will compile.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance.

```
std::vector<RoadSegement*>::iterator segIt;
std::vector<RoadSegement*>::iterator nextSegIt;

for (segIt = nextSegIt = m_segmentArray.begin(); segIt != m_segmentArray.end(); segIt++)
{
    nextSegIt++;
    (*segIt)->calculateVectors((*segIt)->getRoadSegmentCoords().at(3), (*segIt)->getRoadSegmentCoords().at(2), (*nextSegIt)->getRoadSegmentCoords().at(3));
}
```

`RoadSegment` constructor

```
RoadSegement::RoadSegement()
{
    m_roadSegment.push_back(glm::vec3(-1, +1, 0));
    m_roadSegment.push_back(glm::vec3(-1, -1, 0));
    m_roadSegment.push_back(glm::vec3( 0, +1, 0));
    m_roadSegment.push_back(glm::vec3( 0, -1, 0));
    m_roadSegment.push_back(glm::vec3(+1, +1, 0));
    m_roadSegment.push_back(glm::vec3(+1, -1, 0));

    m_roadWidth = 0.5;
    scale(m_roadWidth);
}
```

`calculateVectors()` function:

```
void RoadSegement::calculateVectors(glm::vec3 _point, glm::vec3 _nextPoint, glm::vec3 _nextNextPoint)
{
    glm::vec3 vector0 = glm::vec3(m_roadSegment.at(2) - _point);
    glm::vec3 vector1 = glm::vec3(m_roadSegment.at(1) - _point);
    glm::vec3 vector2 = glm::vec3(m_roadSegment.at(5) - _point);
    glm::vec3 vector3 = glm::vec3(_nextNextPoint - _nextPoint);
    glm::vec3 vector4 = glm::vec3(m_roadSegment.at(0) - _nextPoint);
    glm::vec3 vector5 = glm::vec3(m_roadSegment.at(4) - _nextPoint);

    m_segmentVectors.push_back(vector0);
    m_segmentVectors.push_back(vector1);
    m_segmentVectors.push_back(vector2);
    m_segmentVectors.push_back(vector3);
    m_segmentVectors.push_back(vector4);
    m_segmentVectors.push_back(vector5);
}
```

Comment: I guess the issue is with the term "exists".  You can test an iterator for within a range.  I don't know if you can test if the container has a value at an iterator's position.  For example, reserving a vector of 10 items.  There are 10 slots, but whether the slots have a valid or existing value is another topic.

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough: check if `nextSegIt == m_segmentArray.end()`.  If so, the element doesn't exist.

If there is no NextNextPoint, you'll have to call a different function obviously.  You could pass a dummy value, but that's not recommended.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. You have helped me to see my problem. The m_segmentArray contains all the segments for all roads. I need to be able to access each road separately. So Im thinking I need either a multimap with the values being a RoadSegment* or a map with the values being a std::vector<RoadSegment*>. Thankyou for your time, but I now realise I have stored it in a way that is not useful for what i need to do.